# Группы безопасности AD

Tags: active-directory, windows-server, synology

Я назначаю права доступа в сетевом хранилище на пользователей. Например в папке "Отделы" сотрудник из отдела "бухгатерия" будет видить и уметь взаимодействовать только с папкой его отдела, по факту в папке "Отделы" множество папок, но из-за разграничения прав доступа пользователь видит только то что должен видеть. Так вот если я назначаю каждую группу безопасностей отдельно на пользователя, то все работает как часы,а вот с автоматической раздачей прав доступа сразу 10 групп безопасности у меня проблема.Так как я создал группу безопасности и запихал туда 10 других групп безопасности которые нужны для конкретной 1 функции, сделал группу локальной для домена( пробовал и просто глобально оставить). Я хочу чтобы пользователь автоматически получал все доступы которые ему назначены при добавлении пользователя в 1 общую группу в которой находятся 10 групп безопасностей. прикреплю картинку как все это выглядит наглядно.Все это реализуетя совместно с synology.
[image: Вот визуализация того про что я говорю]